# A small-appliance manufacturer has plants in Baltimore and Philadelphia, each of which produces toasters and blenders.

Tags: calculus

A small-appliance manufacturer has plants in Baltimore and Philadelphia, each of which produces toasters and blenders. The Baltimore plant can produce at most 800 appliances in one day at a cost of 12  per toaster and 15 per blender. The Philadelphia plant can produce at most 500 appliances in one day at a cost of 10 per toaster and 20 per blender. A rush order is received for 600 toasters and 300 blenders. The manufacturer will choose the number of
toasters and blenders produced at each plant in order to minimize costs.
1) Name in words the four quantities that must be determined.
2) Express the four quantities in (a) algebraically using only the two variables, x and y.
3) Write the complete system of inequalities (in terms of x and y) needed to solve the problem
4) Write the objective function in terms of x and y.

Comment: This is not a realistic question, since all toaster and blenders are manufactured in China nowdays.

Comment: What has your approach been to this problem?

Comment: Was my answer yesterday helpful? You have 7 question with no up votes and no accepted answers.  If an answer is helpful to you you should consider upvoting and accepting it. Otherwise you should ask about what you think is missing in the answer. An advice if you want help in the future.

Comment: Surprised this just hadn't been deleted.